# 3yr old still refusing solids

Tags: eating, speech, solids

My 3yr old son will not eat anything except for Gerber stage 2 purees. He gags on any other food offered and physically refuses it. He drinks while milk with rice cereal added and sometimes flavoring. He will however, let you put a lollipop in his mouth and spin it around, I guess he knows he doesn't have to swallow it. He does have a speech delay and was late walking. Has anyone had a similar experience and how and when did it resolve? We are waiting to have him evaluated by a developmental doctor. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think talking to a doctor is going to be your best bet. However, I do wonder if some sort of tongue tie could be at play here. Look for a dentist that specializes in tongue ties or ENT and they can evaluate for a tie.

Comment: Also, what is "late walking"? I'd specify the age your son started.

Comment: This is decidedly atypical, in that only a small percentage of children are not eating solids at this age. The presence of multiple developmental delays and a pronounced sensory issue is of significant concern. I'm sure others have experienced this, but with multiple issues, it becomes a medical problem, and a medical issue, and how it turned out in others is of very limited value as a specialist (perhaps a team of specialists) is required to diagnose and treat your child.

Comment: Editing the question to improve it is great, but editing the question to change it significantly is not. The OP asked for comparable experiences and outcomes, not possibilities. Being of limited imagination, I can't think of any possibilities that are not, in this case, "medical conditions", and medical questions are off topic on this site.

Answer (score 1):

As a parent of 3 children 4 years and younger, I share your concern! I did a little digging and I found out a few interesting things. However, before I share them, I do want to congratulate you for getting a Dr involved.

In the article [Ask Dr. Sears: Refusing Solid Foods](https://www.parenting.com/baby/ask-dr-sears-refusing-solid-foods/), the author states

> Between 6 and 12 months of age, many babies go through a passing stage of refusing solids and favoring milk...

I know your little guy is older, but you mentioned that he developed a little later in life. Maybe this is another thing that he is developing later than typical.

[www.todaysparent.com](http://www.todaysparent.com) also mentioned something similar

> Between 6 months to a year is when kids develop eating skills...

While I am not a Dr, I am a parent. I would think that he will eventually develop the desire for solid foods as long as you keep trying. I do think the best thing would be to do what you are already doing, getting his Dr involved.

I hope this helps and my heart goes out to you!

Comment: You should really link to the specific pages you found those quotes on. See [the help center on referencing](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Comment: Ok thank you. When I did that in the past, I got accused of spam. I'm just trying to do the right thing.

Comment: @BriHan not here, I hope?